# F# : The record label 'InfNFe' is not defined

Tags: xml, f#, xsd

In F# I used XSD type provider

```
type nfe = XmlProvider<Schema="nfe_v4.00.xsd", ResolutionFolder=xsdFolder (*"c:/temp/nfe"*)>
```

I can instantiate:

```
let i = Unchecked.defaultof<nfe.InfNFe>
let defSign = Unchecked.defaultof<nfe.Signature>

nfe.NFe(infNFe=i, infNFeSupl=None, signature=defSign)
```

but I am unable to create another instance, specifying a single constructor property:

```
let ChangeDest (n: nfe.NFe) =
    let novodest = nfe.Dest(cnpj=None, 
                            cpf=Some "81679580515",
                            idEstrangeiro=None, 
                            xNome=Some "TONY", 
                            enderDest=None,
                            indIeDest="",
                            ie=None,
                            isuf=None, 
                            im=None, 
                            email=Some "tonyvca@hotmail.com"
                            )
    let i = nfe.InfNFe(
                        versao="4.00", 
                        id="NFe123 F#",
                        ide=n.InfNFe.Ide, 
                        emit=n.InfNFe.Emit, 
                        avulsa=None, 
                        dest=Some novodest, 
                        retirada=None, 
                        entrega=None, 
                        autXmLs=Unchecked.defaultof<nfe.AutXml[]>, 
                        dets=Unchecked.defaultof<nfe.Det[]>, 
                        total=Unchecked.defaultof<nfe.Total>, 
                        transp=Unchecked.defaultof<nfe.Transp>, 
                        cobr=None, 
                        pag=Unchecked.defaultof<nfe.Pag>, 
                        infAdic=None, 
                        exporta=None, 
                        compra=None, 
                        cana=None                       
                        )

    //let x = { n with InfNFe = i }          // error FS0039: The record label 'InfNFe' is not defined
    //let x ({ infNFe = i } : nfe.NFe) = n   // error FS0039: The record label 'InfNFe' is not defined
    let x = nfe.NFe(i, n.InfNFeSupl, n.Signature)
    x
```

In that code, if I try:

```
let x = { n with InfNFe = i }
```

I get

> error FS0039: The record label 'InfNFe' is not defined

I only could compile using this:

```
let x = nfe.NFe(i, n.InfNFeSupl, n.Signature)
```

This is the type:

[image: nfe.NFe constructor]

**Is there an way to copy constructors on F#?**
This would be useful specially for type with many constructors like nfe.InfNFe that has 18 parameters in the constructor

Comment: Are you sure you didn't make a typo and actually just want ``let x = { n with infNFe = i }``

Comment: This syntax is for records only, not allowed for types generated by type providers

Comment: The only trick I can think of is to let mutability sneak in through the XElement property of the field to be changed

Comment: Can the F# Type Provider generate Records, instead of Class Constructors?

Comment: Unfortunately no

Comment: Can it have an option on the XmlProvider<Mutable=true/false to generate classes with mutable properties?

Comment: I think it's feasible, but in F# mutability is discouraged. You may try to ask for this feature in F# Data (the xsd project is just a thin wrapper, the code to generate types is in F# Data)

Answer (score 1):

This is what I meant in the comment (let mutability sneak in through the XElement property of the field to be changed)
>

```
type nfe = XmlProvider<Schema="nfe_v4.00.xsd", ResolutionFolder="c:/temp/nfe">

let enderDest1 = nfe.EnderDest("test1", "", None, "", "", "", "", None, None, None, None)
let enderDest2 = nfe.EnderDest("test2", "", None, "", "", "", "", None, None, None, None)
let dest = 
    nfe.Dest(cnpj=None, 
             cpf=Some "81679580515",
             idEstrangeiro=None, 
             xNome=Some "TONY", 
             enderDest=Some enderDest1,
             indIeDest="",
             ie=None,
             isuf=None, 
             im=None, 
             email=Some "tonyvca@hotmail.com")


let replace (dest: nfe.Dest) (enderDest: nfe.EnderDest) =
    match dest.EnderDest with
    | Some x -> x.XElement.ReplaceWith(enderDest.XElement)
    | None -> dest.XElement.Add(enderDest.XElement)

let xml1 = dest.XElement.ToString()

replace dest enderDest2

let xml2 = dest.XElement.ToString()
```